# How do I center inline radiobuttons on the page?

Tags: vmware-clarity

I'm trying to center a group of inline radiobuttons on my webpage but can't seem to override Claritys' CSS styling.

I've tried placing the clarity code inside a parent DIV tag using align-text:center, align-content:center, align-items: center, using a FIELDSET tag. But none of these have worked so far

```
<fieldset style='text-align: center'>
    <div class="clr-form-control">
        <div class="clr-control-container clr-control-inline">
          <div class="clr-radio-wrapper">
            <input type="radio" id="vertical-radio1" name="radio-full" value="option1" class="clr-radio">
            <label for="vertical-radio1" class="clr-control-label">option 1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="clr-radio-wrapper">
            <input type="radio" id="vertical-radio2" name="radio-full" value="option2" class="clr-radio">
            <label for="vertical-radio2" class="clr-control-label">option 2</label>
          </div>
          <div class="clr-radio-wrapper">
            <input type="radio" id="vertical-radio3" name="radio-full" value="option3" class="clr-radio">
            <label for="vertical-radio3" class="clr-control-label">option 3</label>
          </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

The radiobuttons should be centered in the page.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to add your own css class to the `clr-control-container` and set the following for its css:

```
.app-centered-radios {
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Here is a stackblitz with centered inline radio buttons: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-56050259-center-inline-radio-buttons